# Retrieving Record ID for each Opportunity in a list

Tags: apex, data-loader, salesforce-id, bulk-api

I need to retrieve the record ID of all opportunities in a single csv list, and I am wondering if there is a way to do this either with python or Salesforce natively.

Essentially I would need to loop through an entire list, and search for each opportunity name - if a match is found, copy the record ID so that we can update opportunities in bulk in data loader

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export all of the opportunities (`SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity`) using the Data Loader, then use the [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) formula in Excel to match by name. This is a pretty standard task, easy to do in Excel.